# How to divide the area between two co-ordinates into blocks and assign some values to those blocks?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Basically I have to create a heatmap of the crowd present in an area.
I have two coordinates. X starts from 0 and maximum is 119994. Y ranges from -14,000 to +27,000. I have to divide these coordinates into as many blocks blocks as I wish, count the number of people in each block and create a heatmap of this whole area. 
Basically show the crowdedness of the area divided as blocks.

```
I have data in the below format:-
Employee_ID X_coord Y_coord_start Y_coord_end
    23       1333      0           6000
    45       3999    7000          17000
```

I tried dividing both the coordinate maximums by 100(to make 100 blocks) and tried finding the block coordinates but that was very complex.

As I have to make a heatmap I have to prepare a matrix of values in the form of blocks. Every block will have a count of people which I can count and find out from my data but the problem is how to make these blocks of coordinates?

I have another question regarding scatter plot:- 
My data is:-

```
Batch_ID         Pieces_Productivity
181031008780     4.578886
181031008781     2.578886
```

When I plot it using the following code:-

```
plt.scatter(list(df_books_location.Batch_ID),list(df_books_location['Pieces_productivity']), s=area,  alpha=0.5)
```

It doesn't give me proper plot. But when I plot with small integers(0-1000) for Batch_ID I get good graph. How to handle large integers for plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which of both `Y_coord_`-rows should give the actual Y coordinate, and also don't know whether your plot should be evaluate the data on a strict "grid", or perhaps rather smooth it out; hence I am using both an `imshow()` and a `sns.kdeplot()` in the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

### generate some data
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [(1, .6), (.6, 1)], 100)

## this would e.g. be X,Y=df['X_coord'], df['Y_coord_start'] :
X,Y=data[:,0],data[:,1] 


fig,ax=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,figsize=(10,5))
ax[0].scatter(X,Y)
sns.kdeplot(X,Y, shade=True, ax=ax[1],cmap="viridis")
## the X,Y points are binned into 10x10 bins here, you will need 
#  to adjust the amount of bins so that it looks "nice" for you
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(X, Y, bins=(10,10))
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
im=ax[2].imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, 
            origin="lower",aspect="auto",
            interpolation="nearest") ## also play with different interpolations

## Loop over heatmap dimensions and create text annotations:
#  note that we need to "push" the text from the lower left corner of each pixel
#     into the center of each pixel 
## also try to choose a text color which is readable on all pixels, 
#     or e.g. use vmin=… vmax=  to adjust the colormap such that the colors
#     don't clash with e.g. white text

pixel_center_x=(xedges[1]-xedges[0])/2.
pixel_center_y=(yedges[1]-yedges[0])/2.
for i in range(np.shape(heatmap)[1]):
    for j in range(np.shape(heatmap)[0]):
        text = ax[2].text(pixel_center_x+xedges[j], pixel_center_y+yedges[i],'{0:0.0f}'.format(heatmap[j, i]),
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w",fontsize=6)

plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

yields:

[image: Updated plot result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Can I have a way to write the counts of the points plotted in each  block? Like the yellow block should show a number which will be the highest of all as it is the hottest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I want these numbers on the plotted heatmap. Like if I have 10,000 values .. how many of those are plotted in which block? Green block can show 5,dark green can show 8,yellow can show 20.